# theano g++ not available

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, theano, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to import the package theano into my Jupyter notebook, but always receive the following error:

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
>   C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
>     warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
>   WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
>   WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.

I'm using Python version 3.6.6, and I'm on a PC with Windows 10.  I can still run theano but I'd like to address the error.

Tried `import m2w64-toolchain` in Jupyter but error message says `invalid syntax`

I then installed a MinGW GCC/G++ compiler, following directions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXW2VLrQ3Bs) but when I went back to Jupyter and imported theano again the error message changed to this much longer one and stopped working entirely.  Error message is 400+ lines long so won't put the whole thing, but it ends with this:

> Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
>   "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3\include" -I"C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\c_code" -L"C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3\libs" -L"C:\Users\tmgor\Anaconda3" -o "C:\Users\tmgor\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_142_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.6.6-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd" "C:\Users\tmgor\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_142_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.6.6-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp" -lpython36cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

In the end I got rid of the g++ compiler and now I'm back to the original error.  I've read [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713496/installed-g-on-theano-suggestion-now-theano-doesnt-work) but didn't find an answer to my problem. I'm quite new to python so any suggestions welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36722975/10149003